# Fluent Mappings / Data Annotations for Unique columns and navigation properties with differant names in Entity Framework 4.1?

Tags: mapping, data-annotations, entity-framework-4.1, fluent-interface

First, is there a way to tell EF 4.1 that a column needs to be unique by using either data annotations or the fluent API?

Second, regarding navigation properties, I have have 2 classes Document and User. In the document class I have a property for the OwnerId (UserId) and a property for Owner (User). How do I tell EF 4.1 that the OwnerId is really UserId and Owner is a navigation property back to User?

The Document Class:

```
public abstract class Document: BaseEntity
    {
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        //The UserId
        public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
        //The User
        public User Owner { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx for an example of a key property made unique using validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entity framework doesn't support unique keys at all so the answer to your first question is no.

`OwnerId` should be recognized as foreign key for `Owner` automatically unless you map to existing database where the foreign key is named differently. In such case you can use for example:

```
public abstract class Document: BaseEntity
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Column("UserId"), ForeignKey("Owner")]
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
}
```

Foreign key data annotation is probably not needed but you can use it to explicitly pair your FK property with navigation property.

In fluent mapping you can use:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
            .Property(d => d.OwnerId)
            .HasColumnName("UserId");
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
            .HasRequired(d => d.Owner)
            .WithMany(...)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.OwnerId);
```

Comment: So, my validations will have to look for duplicate entires, correct? That makes sense from a business concept, because not all systems will need that requirement. As always, great answer!